# What is the Expectation of Square of Wiener Process?

Tags: expected-value, random-walk, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to find $E[W(t)^2\cdot e^{-2at}]$, where $a$ is a constant and $W(t)$ is the Wiener Process. This arises when finding the variance of the Vasicek interest rate model. I think it should be $t$ since $dW^2=dt$ but not sure. The $e^{-2at}$ term should come out of the expectation but I dont know how to calculate $E[W(t)^2]$. Kindly help.

Comment: Isn't $W(t)$ just a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $t$? Unless the "Weiner process" is actually something different from the well-known Wiener process.

Comment: @MishaLavrov yes it is the wiener process. sorry for the typo. but will the expectation of the square of wiener process also equal 0?

Comment: $W_t$ is a centered Gaussian with variance $t$

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Vasicek Model follows the SDE

$$
dr_t = k[\theta - r_t]dt + \sigma dW_t
$$

and has solution $r_t = r(s)e^{-k(t-s)} +\theta (1-e^{-k(t-s)})+\sigma \int_{s}^{t}e^{-k(t-u)}dW_u$.

To compute the variance, we can notice that the first two terms are deterministic and so give no contribution and we are left with

$$
\text{Var}(r_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}\bigg[\bigg(\int_{s}^{t}e^{-k(t-u)}dW_u\bigg)^2\bigg]=\text{Ito Isometry} \\
= \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_{s}^{t}e^{-2k(t-u)}du\bigg] = \frac{\sigma^2}{2k}(1-e^{-2k(t-s)})
$$

I believe the mistake was to "take out" the exponential in the stochastic integral. This is not allowed since it depends on time and is not constant.